# Jquery datatables remove horizontal line

Tags: jquery, datatables

Need help, I'm trying to remove the horizontal line in jQuery Datatables.

Please see screenshot below:
[image]
I'm trying to find the line using google chrome element inspector but no luck.

Answer (score 12):

Those distinct lines is rendered by the `<th>` elements in `<thead>` and `<tfoot>`. Use

```css
table.dataTable thead th {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
table.dataTable tfoot th {
  border-top: 0;
}
```

...to remove them. Demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/dgsccstp/** try comment out the CSS and re-run.

---

If you not have specified any footer, ie not having a `<tfoot></tfoot>` section, remove the bottom line this way :

```css
table.dataTable.no-footer {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

---

If you have multiple DataTables and only want to remove the borders of one (or more) specific table, replace `table` with the table `#id` as selector :

```css
#example1.dataTable thead th {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#example1.dataTable tfoot th {
  border-top: 0;
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Ljortyx8/**

Comment: My datable have no footer (tfoot) i tried your css but the horizontal line in the bottom is still visible.

Comment: You must show exactly what dataTables setup you have - there are dozens of ways, it is hard to guess. The above is on standard setup, you seem to perhaps use the bootstrap plugin?

Comment: Consider a scenario where you have more than one dataTable and you only need to remove the border on a specific table, what is the element selector that one needs to use? e.g if `<table id="mydataTable" datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" dt-instance="dtInstanceCallback" class="mydataTables"></table>` using `#mydataTable thead th{}` or `.mydataTables thead th{}` in css doesn't seem to select the dataTable.

Comment: @rey_coder, use `#mydataTable.dataTable thead th` etc, see update.

Comment: @davidkonrad, I am using [angular datatables](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/) . and i have realized a div wrapper created around the table which takes the table id and appends '_wrapper' to form its id leaving the table element without an id. thus for me it had to be something like `#example1_wrapper .datatTable thead th{border-bottom:0;}` Thanks.

Comment: Hey @rey_coder, there is no difference between jQuery DataTables and Angular DataTables, they both have the `id*_wrapper` element. See a angular-datatables demo with the above CSS here -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/GWAXtj5M7qagso2rvYaA?p=preview**

Answer (score 4):

I'm not using the tfoot so the dark line at the end of the table is generated in the tbody. I have removed it adding this CSS code:

```
table.dataTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it is in css:

table.dataTable.display tbody td

It is the border top:

```
border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
```

for each cell.

or only for the header:

in the css:

```
<thead>
 <th>
  <td>
Td property:
border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
```

To test it you can uncheck property in css inspector.

for me it works, as you can see:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I already removed the border line by using this css
 table.dataTable thead th, table.dataTable thead td {
            border-bottom: none!important;
        }

the only left now is the bottom horizontal line.

Answer (score 1):

these are the default style selectors of datatables . those line apear because of border bottom property..

in below css I overided boder bottom property with  none ! with important.

```
table.dataTable thead th {
  border-bottom: none !important;
}
table.dataTable.no-footer {
  border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -1):

If your data table doesn't have a footer (because of your configuration options) @davidkonrad's solution won't work.  However, you can still use that solution if you add a footer, and then hide it using CSS :)